# ClassA childNodeWithName:@"name" not working inside ClassB

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am trying to create an invisible pathway out of strategically placed SKSpriteNodes inside my RPG map for my NPC's to walk to and from (to make the map look more lively). Then I want to create a looped method inside my NPC's class that will move it from one of these invisible SKSpriteNode's to another. All is good except the actual movement of the NPC. More precisely I am unable to access my SKScene's invisible node's position from inside my NPC class which is a SKSpriteNode. I create several of the invisible pathway node's and here is how 1 is done inside my SKScene:

```
TMXObjectGroup *group = [_tileMap groupNamed:@"WalkingPath"];

NSDictionary *s1node1 = [group objectNamed:@"street1Node1"];
if (s1node1)
{
    CGFloat x = [s1node1[@"x"] floatValue];
    CGFloat y = [s1node1[@"y"] floatValue];
    CGFloat w = [s1node1[@"width"] floatValue];
    CGFloat h = [s1node1[@"height"] floatValue];

    SKSpriteNode *object = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(w, h)];
    object.name = @"strt1N1";
    object.position = CGPointMake(x + w/2, y + h/2);

    object.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(w, h)];

    object.physicsBody.categoryBitMask       = terrainCategory;
    object.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask    = playerCategory | npcCategory;
    object.physicsBody.collisionBitMask      = 0;
    object.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    object.physicsBody.friction = 0;
    object.hidden = YES;

    [_worldNode addChild:object];
}
```

Once all of the above code compiles and the app runs, everything is created as it should be. So that's good. But, when trying to access this exact node from with in my NPC class nothing happens. I used an IF statement to check if such a node exists. The console says it doesn't... vwaAt?? Here is the movement method, inside the NPC class, trying to access the SKScene's childNode:

```
-(void)beginMovement
{
    //_oTC is a @property (@property OTC *oTC;).
    //_oTC = (OTridentCity*)self.scene; //<---DOESN'T DO ANYTHING.
    //_oTC = [[OTridentCity alloc] init]; //<---DESTROYS THE APP :D
    //[_oTC childNodeWithName:@"strt1N1"]; //<---Lazy reference.

    if ([_oTC childNodeWithName:@"strt1N1"]) //<---VY NO WERK????
    {
        NSLog(@"EXISTS!"); //<---VANT DIS!!!!!!
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"DOESN'T EXIST"); //<---POPS OUT EVERY TIME.
    }


    CGPoint aPoint      = CGPointMake([_oTC childNodeWithName:@"strt1N1"].position.x, [_oTC childNodeWithName:@"strt1N1"].position.y);
    SKAction *move      = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(aPoint.x, aPoint.y) duration:3.0];
    SKAction *wait      = [SKAction waitForDuration:4.0 withRange:4.0];


    //NPC does move, but it seems towards coordinates (0, 0).
    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[move, wait]] completion:^{ /*[self beginMovement];*/ NSLog(@"Moving"); }];
}
```

Am I forgetting something in regards to accessing childNodes from SKScene inside a SKSpriteNode class?

Comment: What do you see if you use `NSLog(@"OTC object: %@", _otc);`?

Comment: Hmm, says: OTC object: (null). So how do I properly access _oTC then? It is #imported correctly into NPC class after all.

Comment: The property declaration is just a pointer.  Something needs to assign it an actual object before you make it do things.  Does the object that creates the "strt1N1" node have a reference to your NPC object?

Comment: ...or possibly the NPC can get it by name from `_worldNode`?  (It really depends on how your objects are connected.)

Comment: I see. Well, I did this inside the NPC's movement method: OTC *aScene = (OTC*)self.scene; Now NSLog(@"OTC object: %@", aScene); shows that the object exists. The only thing is I have never used this way to check for existing nodes. If I write aScene.worldNode.etc. then that works. But how would I access worldNodes childNodeWithName?

Comment: I tried this [aScene.worldNode childNodeWithName:@"strt1N1"] and it worked. I'm a dumbass. I need to stop programming after 9pm. Sorry about that.